# Trying to combine observations repeated in a single column

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```
Year Count        Common.name     County
1 1993     0 Spotted Salamander Bennington
2 1993     6 Spotted Salamander Bennington
3 1993    12       Eastern Newt Bennington
4 1993    23       Eastern Newt Bennington
5 1993     1      American Toad Bennington
6 1993     2          Wood Frog Bennington
```

Here is what I want my data to look like:

```
Year Count        Common.name     County
1 1993     6 Spotted Salamander Bennington
2 1993    35       Eastern Newt Bennington
3 1993    97      American Toad Bennington
4 1993     2          Wood Frog Bennington
5 1993   209         Green Frog Bennington
6 1994    78 Spotted Salamander Chittenden
```

I have data from 1993 - 2017, sampling different counties on different dates. I would like to combine the year, count, and county for a given species. I don't know how to add them together appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is `aggregate`.

```
DAT = read.table(text='Year Count        Common.name     County
1 1993     0 "Spotted Salamander" Bennington
2 1993     6 "Spotted Salamander" Bennington
3 1993    12       "Eastern Newt" Bennington
4 1993    23       "Eastern Newt" Bennington
5 1993     1      "American Toad" Bennington
6 1993     2          "Wood Frog" Bennington',
header=TRUE)

aggregate(DAT$Count, list(DAT$Year, DAT$Common.name, DAT$County), sum)
  Group.1            Group.2    Group.3  x
1    1993      American Toad Bennington  1
2    1993       Eastern Newt Bennington 35
3    1993 Spotted Salamander Bennington  6
4    1993          Wood Frog Bennington  2
```